# calling clojure from Java (Clojure Interop)

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

Calling Java from Clojoure is quite simple and straightforward but the inverse has proven to be unpredictable.

They seem to be two ways of doing it:

> 1)the following classes
>
> ```
>       i) import clojure.java.api.Clojure; ,
>      ii) import clojure.lang.IFn;
> ```
>
> 2)compile your clojure into an uberjar then import it into the java
>   code.

I have opted for the 2nd option as it's more straight forward.

Here is the clojure code

```
(ns com.test.app.service
 (:gen-class
       :name com.test.app.service
       :main false
       :methods [^{:static true} [returned [int] int]]))

    (defn returned
      [number]
      (* 2 number))

    (defn -returned
      [number]
      (returned number))
```

Here is the Java code.

```
package com.s.profile;

import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.serverless.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.serverless.functions.*;
import com.test.app.service;


/**
 * Azure Functions with HTTP Trigger.
 */
public class Function {
    /**
     * This function listens at endpoint "/api/hello". Two ways to invoke it using "curl" command in bash:
     * 1. curl -d "HTTP Body" {your host}/api/hello
     * 2. curl {your host}/api/hello?name=HTTP%20Query
     */
    @FunctionName("hello")
    public HttpResponseMessage<String> hello(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {"get", "post"}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        // Parse query parameter
        String query = request.getQueryParameters().get("name");
        String name = request.getBody().orElse(query);

        if (name == null) {
            return request.createResponse(400, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        } else {
            service.returned(4);
            context.getLogger().info("process data" );
            return request.createResponse(200, "Hellos, " + name );
        }
    }
}
```

When ever I make the "service.returned(4);" the system never returns. I can't quite figure out why to me it comes off like the function doesn't return from Clojure but I can't see the cause.

Just to add some context I have tried it when its a simple hello world java app which just prints out the result and it works. It's when I try implement it in the Azure functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168154/how-to-add-dependency-jar-in-java-azure-functions) and it seemed to resolve the error of class not found. It seems as though when running the command

```
mvn azure-functions:run
```

It doesn't automatically find all imported libraries. You either have to use

1. maven-assembly-plugin
2. maven-shade-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Please see this question for a running example:

[How to invoke Clojure function directly from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46436476/how-to-invoke-clojure-function-directly-from-java)

I would suggest simplifying your code at first, then adding back in the Azure stuff one line at a time in case some interaction there is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you but as stated that is not the method I am going for. Also i forgot to mention but have  since updated the question it works on a basic hello world meaning the Clojure is fine.