# How do I add Java Azure Functions in a Maven submodule

Tags: java, azure, maven, azure-functions

#### Problem description

I have my Java library A and I create a new Azure Functions module B (following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-intellij), which should use A as a dependency.

Now:

- if I create B as a new and **standalone** module, it works;
- if I add B as another **submodule of a common parent C**, it does not.

More specifically: no problems with compilation, running and deployment of my functions, but when any of them is triggered I get a **ClassNotFoundException** for each class defined in A. And no wonder it happens, since A.jar is not present in the *lib* subfolder of the Azure Function's run folder (something like *{myUser}\AppData\Local\Temp\azure-functions16636049357177434984* on my Windows PC in case of local run). But I don't understand why the dependency jar is not copied there, especially that after compilation it's present in the *target\azure-functions\taxclaims-azure-1596530670055\lib* folder of my IntelliJ project.

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

---

#### Minimal example

I have **TestParent** Java Maven project, with two modules:

- ***dependency-module***
- ***azure-functions-module*** (depending on ***dependency-module***)

In ***dependency-module*** I have a *DependencyClass* with empty body, whereas in ***azure-functions-module*** I have *HttpTriggerFunction* class with the following method:

```
@FunctionName("TestFunction")
public HttpResponseMessage run(
@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request, final ExecutionContext context) 
{
   DependencyClass instance = new DependencyClass();
   return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("OK").build();
}
```

This module can be successfully deployed, but when the *TestFunction* is triggered, I obtain **ClassNotFoundException** for *DependencyClass*.

However, if I create **another** project, called **TestStandaloneParent**, with a module ***standalone-azure-functions-module*** and the same function as above, then everything works smoothly.

*If needed of course I can add further details, especially the pom.xml files.*

Comment: Does the `azure-functions-module` module reference the dependency of the `dependency-module` module?

Comment: Yes, I have the suitable dependency in azure-functions-module's pom.xml:

      `<dependency>`
            `<groupId>org.example</groupId>`
            `<artifactId>dependency-module</artifactId>`
           `<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>`
       `</dependency>`

Comment: Stupid question: did you analyse the packaged result if your library is packed together with it? Like unpacking it?

Comment: You mean checking whether the dependency is not inside the jar? No, it's not there.

Comment: I have run into the same problem, but I concur with Tomek's conclusion. 

The IntelliJ plugin does not use the Maven pom, nor the Maven build,
but IntelliJ's internal project structure.

See Project Settings/Modules/Dependencies: when two modules 
are open in the same project, they are listed as module dependencies, not Maven:dependencies. I am fairly certain that the Azure plugin is unable to 
process those. 
When the upstream modules are not in the same project, OR, I run the app
via maven azure-functions:run, everything is fine

Comment: Looks like the issue has been addressed
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-tools-for-java/issues/7063

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this other question here: [How to add dependency JAR in java azure functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168154/how-to-add-dependency-jar-in-java-azure-functions)

It looks like a problem with the packaging, you need to tweak it by using the maven assembly plugin config manually.

Comment: Thanks, the link is really useful. Following the approach described there, I have managed to make Maven create a jar with dependencies instead of the "simple" one. However, this only in the target folder of my project. On run/deploy the .jar is still the old one, and I'm quite perplexed about this. I need to spend more time investigating this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like IntelliJ Azure Plugin doesn't use pom.xml.
What you can do is to go File->Project structure->Project settings->Modules, choose module with Azure Functions and manually add jar fil as a dependency.
In my case I achieve the result, but I'm not happy with the way of solution.